# Link to pages of PDFs created with GhostScript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We have created PDFs from converting individual PostScript pages into a single PDF (and embedding appropriate fonts) using GhostScript.

We've found that an individual page of the PDF cannot be linked to; for example, through the usage of

```
 http://xxxx/yyy.pdf#page=24
```

There must be something within the PDF that makes this not possible. Are there any specific GhostScript options that should be passed when creating the PDF that would allow this type of page-destination link to work?

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific pdfwrite (the Ghostscript device which actually produces PDF) options to do this. Without knowing *why* the (presumably) web browser or plugin won't open the file at the specified page its a little difficult to offer any more guidance.

What are you using to view the PDF files ?

Can you make a *very* simple file that fails ? Can you make that file public ?

If I can reproduce the problem, and the file is sufficiently simple, it may be possible to determine the problem. By the way, which version of Ghostscript are you using ?